# Breaking the law of conservation of energy with wormholes?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, energy-conservation, momentum, wormholes

How don't wormholes violate the conservation of energy and momentum?
Picture the following situation: a scientist creates a wormhole connecting the ceiling of a room with the floor. The two openings of the wormhole are vertically aligned, so if someone dropped an object in the entrance near the floor, it would "appear" instantly in the entrance near the ceiling and fall down to the floor because of gravity. And since both entrances are vertically aligned, the object would repeat the process, falling in the entrance near the floor and "appearing" near the ceiling again. This would create a loop that accelerates the object. Now imagine that the object is a
magnet. If we constructed a coil around the falling object, we would
basically create free infinite energy!!! Could this idea work? If not, why? And if yes, how is this even possible due to the law of conservation of energy?

Please help me not to freak out with this question in mind hahaha! Thank
you!

Comment: [This has already been asked many times](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Wormhole+conservation+energy)

Comment: I think you're confusing "portals" (as in the game) with wormholes but it really depends on the model of wormhole you use. Primarily whether forces should still carry through the wormhole (so the opening in the ceiling is transmitting that pull you feel at the floor) so rather than have a single downwards force your object will feel the same force of gravity in the middle pulling it upwards.